# Parse XML and replace values from different data source

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, spring-batch, etl

I have a lot of XML with size <= 256kb having a below structure

```
<node>
    <id>XXX</id>
    <value1></value1>
    <value2></value2>
    <value3></value3>
    <value4></value4>
</node>
```

Now I have a requirement which I need to use id as XXX to fetch data from an Rest API and the API will return a list of data. I have to map list of returned data to fields 'value1', 'value2', ...

The API curl http://example.com/api/getById/XXX return value1=V1, value2=V2, value3=V3, value4=V4

The output will be

```
<node>
    <id>XXX</id>
    <value1>V1</value1>
    <value2>V2</value2>
    <value3>V3</value3>
    <value4>V4</value4>
</node>
```

We would like to use Java related technologies to fullfil the requirement.

So far I'm thinking of couple below options

1. Load XML as Java POJO and then write pure java logic with if else logic to call REST API and then update POJO and write back to XML.
2. Load XML as xpath and put mapping logic to a configuration

I also thinking of options such as using camel or spring batch.

Please advice if you have experience on the same with advantage and disadvantages. Or if you have a different approach please share.

Comment: Can you please rephrase the case and requirements? For example I dont understand how solution 2 can do the same as 1. Do you need to process incoming XML files and populate them? Is the load expected to be high?

Comment: This is definitely something that Spring Batch does regularly.  With it's `StaxEventItemReader` for declarative reading of the XML it becomes pretty easy to do.  If you have specific questions about what it would look like in Spring Batch, please ask.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMinella. I'm thinking Spring Batch for this use case is a bit heavy to process a file around 256KB. I'm looking for something lightweight and fast for this process.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.  You've probably typed more in this question and comment responses than it would take in code in Spring Batch to write this job.  If it is a throw a way process, you can use an in memory database for the job repository.  You say you have "a lot of small XML files"...Spring Batch handles all your requirements easily.

Comment: Hello @MichaelMinella - I'm only discovering Spring Batch and I'm curious: how would the implementation looks like in the case of Batch? Would you be able to share a partial implementation here?

Comment: Hi @ThibautBarrère, for this use case, the reader from Spring Batch will load the XML into an object and the processor will handle API call and update fields and then the writer will persist the object to the XML file again.

Answer (score 0):

For this line of work, you can use [Kiba ETL](http://kiba-etl.org) (disclaimer: I'm the author), an ETL framework which works with both JRuby (Ruby on the JVM - which allows you to use any Java component if you want) or "regular" Ruby.

Typically, this would look like this:

```rb
source Kiba::Common::Sources::Enumerable, -> { Dir["input/*.xml"] }

# read each file
transform { |r| IO.binread(r) }

# parse as XML document
transform { |r| Nokogiri::XML(r) }

# this will return an array of XML elements
transform { |r| r.search('/the-root/node') }

# this will explode the array (one order per output row)
transform Kiba::Common::Transforms::EnumerableExploder

# now achieve look-up via REST API
transform do |r|
  the_id = r.at('id').text()
  # achieve your HTTP rest query here then remap, e.g.:
  response = HTTParty.get('http://example.com', query: { the_id: the_id })
  # ... more processing
  r.merge(... your response extracted fields ...)
end
```

In-memory parsing will work nicely for the size of files you have. If you start having to process much larger files, you can switch to SAX parsing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is giving me a direction. For the code example, how can i update field value 1,2.3 from response object?

Comment: It depends on what your API is returning exactly. Can you provide a example of output from the API? (e.g. JSON or XML?)